# The [builder] needs to construct two tags

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag [builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builder) refers to at least two concepts:

- The builder pattern. Example: [Spring: Using builder pattern to create a bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236850/spring-using-builder-pattern-to-create-a-bean)
- A Ruby library called "builder". Example: [Why does Ruby Builder::XmlMarkup add inspect tag to xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971225/why-does-ruby-builderxmlmarkup-add-inspect-tag-to-xml)

There are some others that I don't understand. Example: [Dialog throwing "Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi)

Because people will mess things up if there's a "builder" tag, we should create a "builder-pattern" tag, a "builder-gem" tag, and depopulate "builder".